# The simplest cURL code won't execute script in the CURLOPT_URL option

Tags: php, curl

How can a cURL code be more basic? Yet I can't get it to output - hello cURL! - on the browser. Please help!

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/ita2/test.php");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is the test.php script:

```
<?php
echo "hello cURL!";
?>
```

Comment: Probably some error occurs. But since you do not have any error detection or handling at all, you do not recognize that. I suggest you take a look at your http servers error log file. That is where php logs errors to.

Comment: add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, True);` to debug

Comment: Sorry! tried, but couldn't figure out how to get to  http servers error log file. I'm using phpstorm 8.0.1 with PHP built-in Web Server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got the followin info:

hello cURL!*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 63342 (#0)
> GET /ita2/test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:63342
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8
< Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: PhpStorm 8.0.1
< Content-Length: 11
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Process finished with exit code 0

--- what next?

Comment: uhm, I think it works since there is `hello cURL!` as a part of your output